# Take mean of column 2 values for items that fall within first quintile values of column 1

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have three columns. One identifier column and two numeric columns. We'll call them Identifier, A, and B, respectively.

I have found the first quintile average value within column A and would like to calculate the average of the column B but only for the identifiers that fall within the first quintile of column A. So for the identifiers in the column A first quintile, I want to find the column B average.

I found the first quintile leveraging:

```
df.A.quantile([1])
```

Now I want to find the average of column B for the identifiers that make up the column A first quintile. For example:

| Identifier | A | B |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 8 |
| B | 2 | 7 |
| C | 3 | 6 |
| D | 4 | 5 |
| E | 5 | 4 |
| F | 6 | 3 |
| G | 7 | 2 |
| H | 8 | 1 |

The first quintile of column A consists of identifier G and H and lies at a value of 7.5. I would like to take the average of column B for those identifiers to arrive at 1.5.

Any help in this endeavor would be much appreciated!

Best,
Kilian

Comment: Rename the columns of your dataframe, please. It's so confusing: `Identifier` is column A, `A` is column B and `B` is column C. And your rows have the name of columns...

Comment: I think you misunderstood `quantile` for to mean quartile, `quantile(1)` is the same as `max()`. For the first quartile, you need to use `quantile(0.25)`